# different thread blocks definition

Tags: matlab, cuda, gpu

I'm using PTX from matlab to call CUDA kernels, when testing the code on VS 2010 like this:

```
int TPB = 256; 
int BPG = (Nx + TPB -1 ) / TPB;
dim3 blk(TPB,TPB,1);
dim3 grid(BPG ,BPG,1);
grad<<< grid,blk>>>(dev_y,dev_x,dev_b,dev_t,Nx,Ny);
```

trying to use the same configuration in matlab

```
TPB = 16; 
BPG = floor((Nx + TPB -1 ) / TPB);
grad = parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel('reg.ptx','reg.cu','grad');
grad.ThreadBlockSize=[TPB TPB 1];
grad.GridSize = [BPG BPG];
```

knowning it's more than 512 thread per block which is the allowed number for my TESLA C1060, and I was right

```
Invalid size input to kernel ThreadBlockSize. You must provide a vector of up to 3 positive   integers whose product is <= 512. The maximum value in each dimension is: [512,512,64].
```

any explanation why it's run correctly on VS 2010 without error like what happened in MATLAB?

Comment: The C++ version at the top can't possibly be running, you are asking for a 256x256 block size. The Matlab and C++ versions aren't the same at all.

Comment: Also the call to `CUDAkernel` must contain "a string that unambiguously defines the appropriate kernel entry name in the PTX file". I *very* much doubt the kernel is identified as 'grad' in the PTX file....

Comment: The C++ code segment is not checking a for errors after grad<<<>>>. The MATLAB wrapper has additional error checking. The top code segment will generate an error in the <<<>>> which you can query for with cudaGetLastError.

Comment: @pyCuda: Are you planning on ever doing anything with this question, or has it been abandoned?

Comment: i gave @GregSmith +1 for his comment, but i'm not sure it's the right one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ code segment is not checking for errors after grad<<<>>>. The MATLAB wrapper has additional error checking. The launch configuration is out of bounds. Calling cudaGetLastError after the <<<>>> will report the launch configuration error.